# How to edit Bokeh DataTable row height?

Tags: javascript, python, css, datatable, bokeh

I currently have a `Bokeh` app written in python in directory format.

I am using `Bokeh`'s `DataTable` to display a bunch of raw text in one of the cells, and I cannot figure out how to get back into that CSS to change the default `rowHeight`.

I know the default `slickgrid` `rowHeight` is `25px`, and that isn't enough. Does anyone know how I can go about changing the default `rowHeight` as simply as possible, either in a CSS sheet, in the HTML, or from the python itself?

I do not need it to vary, just want to set it to be a certain pixel value.

Comment: See [ask] and especially [mcve]. Tell us what you want to do, show what you have tried, and share what results you got. You aren't going to get much traction without showing some code and explaining what research you have done.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if there is an easy way to change the `rowHeight` property of the SlickGrid. But if the problem is that you think the table is too small, you can simulate the zoom effect (in the whole table) with the [CSS scale property](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/transform#scale):

```
transform: scale(1.2);
```

Check this [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/teZRm/). And as it is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24425982/4891717):

> Don't forget to specify a transform origin to `0 0` so that the top/left of your element isn't cropped by the viewport.

Anyway I believe the cells contents fit well in the table by default.